# Bootstrap different col-* with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a movie reviews example application built in angular + bootstrap, I'm trying to build a "grid" of 3 images for medium and up screens, the problem is that when I want to have only 2 images per row for xs screens.

I'm using ng-repeat and populating the imgs inside the cols.

is there a nice way to do this? (I'm aware that the $index + N may be out of bounds, and that there is code duplication here. just want to find a good solution for rearranging the bootstrap grid for different screen sizes on dynamic data)

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" class="row slide-left">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index].poster_path}}' ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index])">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index + 1].poster_path}}" ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index + 1])">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index + 2].poster_path}}" ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index + 2])">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies" >
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <img ng-src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movie.poster_path}}' ng-click="chooseMovie(movie)">
  </div>
</div>
```

This should do the trick.

I removed the row but i think even with it will works unless you use the clearfix class.

The grid will automatically go on the next line after "12" columns.

So a size of 4 for medium screen means 3 per line, 6 for xs screen ->2/line :)

Comment: One of the main purposes of the `row` class is to eliminate the `col-*` classes margin so you can stack them without wasting space in paddings, e.g. `.row > .col-* > .row > .col-* > ...`.

Comment: And if i remember well as long you don't use clearfix, the cols will go to new lines if you go further than 12, but i'm not really sure :p.

Comment: Tried this already, but for some reason the grid is not showing right (sometimes, there is only one image in a "row" (not actual row, as i removed that div, a row on the screen that is). might be because I'm using ng infinite scroll library?

Comment: @Walfrat thats correct. They are just floating elements.

Comment: @OmriManor: No. My blind guess would be that an element somewhere inside your col is wider than the col want's to be. E.g. the col wants it's width to be 200px in the current screen size and your img's width is 300px. Result: the img streches the col to something like 300px. 
It can be any element so use your inspector to see which element is so wide. If it's really the img, try making use of bootstraps `img-responsive` class (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive).

Answer (score 0):

You can detect bootstrap columns by using the following function:

```
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
var envs = ["ExtraSmall", "Small", "Medium", "Large"];
var envValues = ["xs", "sm", "md", "lg"];

var $el = $('<div>');
$el.appendTo($('body'));

for (var i = envValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var envVal = envValues[i];

    $el.addClass('hidden-'+envVal);
    if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
        $el.remove();
        return envs[i]
    }
};
```

}

The setting a value to the scope based on the return

```
if(findBootstrapEnvironment()==="Medium"|(findBootstrapEnvironment()==="Large"|){
$scope.size="Medium"
}else{
$scope.size="Small"
}
```

And then with ng-if you can manage the div to be with 3 or 2 photos like this

Three photos if medium

```
    <div ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-if="size==medium" class="row slide-left">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index].poster_path}}' ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index])">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index + 1].poster_path}}" ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index + 1])">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index + 2].poster_path}}" ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index + 2])">
    </div>
</div>
```

Two photos if small

```
    <div ng-repeat="movie in movies" ng-if="size==small" class="row slide-left">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img ng-src='http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index].poster_path}}' ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index])">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/{{movies[$index + 1].poster_path}}" ng-click="chooseMovie(movies[$index + 1])">
    </div>
</div>
```